# Java 8 Spring MVC the best way to read a file in a service class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In java spring MVC Application I have a text file under resources folder,
What'is the most efficient way to read this file from a service class? Can I read this file if I deploy the application like a war on AWS?

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(fileLocationInClasspath);
InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

or

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileLocationInClasspath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Class Loader** to get files from **recourse folder** .

```
  ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        result.append(line).append("\n");
    }

    scanner.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of those would work, and the difference in performance is unlikely to be significant<sup>1</sup>.   I expect that (under the hood) the Spring APIs in the first fragment are actually doing the same thing as the second fragment.  Hence, my guess is that the second one will be marginally faster.

Those two code fragments do not actually read a file.  Rather, they open a file (on the classpath) for reading.  Both fragments deliver an `InputStream`, and the actual performance for reading the file will depend on how you use the `InputStream`.  (This will be more significant to performance, especially if the file is large.)

> I read this file if I deploy the application like a war on AWS?

Yes.

---

<sup>1 - This looks like "premature optimization" to me.  My advice would be to get the code to work, and only optimize this if 1) the *measured* performance indicates that performance is needed, and 2) profiling tells you that *this* part of your code is a *real* performance bottleneck.</sup>

Comment: @NasKehil - why did you post your code as an answer?  It is not an answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for now:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/deals.txt");


public void getDealsFromFile() throws IOException {
   InputStream dfis = resource.getInputStream();

   try (BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(new 
                             InputStreamReader(dfis))) {
       String dline = brd.readLine();
       while (dline != null) {
         String dealFields[] = dline.split(";");

         Deal deal = new Deal();
         deal.setId(Integer.parseInt(dealFields[3]));
         deal.setDealNumber(dealFields[7]);
         deal.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(dealFields[8]));
         dline = brd.readLine();
       }
      brd.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: 1)  This is not an answer to your question.  2) Assuming that this is an attempt to solicit comments on the code efficiency ... a) it might be more efficient to use a Scanner rather than reading lines and splitting them, b) if you **really** care about performance, use a binary representation for the data.